# PerformanceTiming.navigationStart deprecated

Tags: performance, time, browser

According to mdn [navigationStart](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/PerformanceTiming/navigationStart), we can use PerformanceNavigationTiming interface instead. But I can't find a way to get any thing equal to  `performance.timing.navigationStart + performance.now()`, which is approximately equal to Date.now().

Some says performance.timeOrigin, but my test shows that performance.timeOrigin is not equal to performance.timing.navigationStart.
In chrome
`performance.timeOrigin -  performance.timing.navigationStart = -951855.3999023438`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are facing a [bug in Chrome 106](https://crbug.com/1365808). `performance.timeOrigin` is indeed what you want and it should indeed be *close to* `performance.timing.navigationStart`. There is even a [WPT](https://wpt.live/hr-time/timeOrigin.html) (that Chrome 106 fails).

This bug has already been reported and should be fixed in the next versions of Chrome, we just have to wait for it.

Comment: Thank you! Earlier I tested it it in Chrome 107. But it works just fine in firefox and safari.